# Change Magento collection to show only grouped products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to modify Magento (1.7.0.2) collection to show only grouped products in the product list. I've tried to do this with *addAttributeToSelect* or *addAttributeToFilter* like this

```
$_productCollection=$this ->getLoadedProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','grouped');
```

or

```
$_productCollection=$this ->getLoadedProductCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
```

but it's not working now with this version of Magento.

Anybody knows how can I get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Filters not being applied often happens when the production is already loaded.

Try doing a `$_productCollection->clear()` before you iterate across the collection. Preferably though, find a place to update the collection before it is loaded.

Comment: Still the same.. The error is SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user1821715: What does 'echo $_productCollection->getSelect();' return?

Comment: @user1821715: type_id should exist in catalog_product_flat_* table, try reindexing flat (product) catalog.

Comment: @user1821715: What's the output for 'DESCRIBE catalog_product_flat_1;'?

Comment: @user1821715: That error is simply impossible with the select statement, so I'm not really sure what's wrong.

Comment: @DanielSloof, Have you got any solution for this?